# How to send integer in POST to Tornado's AsyncHTTPTestCase.fetch()?

Tags: python, tornado, httpresponse

I'm using python's Tornado framework to test my HTTP POST endpoint. To do this, I'm using the [**fetch**](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/testing.html#tornado.testing.AsyncHTTPTestCase.fetch) method.

```
    data = urllib.urlencode({
        'integer_arg': 1,
        'string_arg': 'hello'
    })

    resp = AsyncHTTPTestCase.fetch('/endpoint', 
                                   method='POST',
                                   headers={'h1': 'H1', 
                                            'h2': 'H2',
                                            'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, 
                                   body=data)
```

When I do this, the endpoint receives `integer_arg` as the string `"1"` even though I want it to receive it as an integer. This is understandable because `urllib.urlencode` converts it to a string. **So how can I ensure it receives an integer?** 
Just eliminating the call to `urllib.urlencode` doesn't work.

By the way, when I hit the same endpoint with a naked curl call as shown below, the endpoint properly receives `integer_arg` as the integer `1`.

```
curl \
--request POST \
--header "h1: H1" \
--header "h2: H2" \
--header "Content-Type: application/json" \
--data '{
    "integer_arg": 1, 
    "string_arg": "hello"
}' \
"http://localhost:8000/endpoint"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The body in `curl` is significantly different than that in `AsyncHTTPClient.fetch`. With python you urlencode the data in curl there is just json. So simply change urlencode with json.dumps:

```
import json
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from tornado.httpclient import AsyncHTTPClient
from tornado.gen import coroutine

@coroutine
def main():
    client = AsyncHTTPClient()
    body = json.dumps({
        'integer_arg': 1,
        'string_arg': 'hello'
    })
    yield client.fetch(
        '/endpoint', method='POST', body=body,
         headers={'h1': 'H1',  'h2': 'H2', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    )

ioloop = IOLoop.instance()
ioloop.run_sync(main)
```